# how to select the last value entered to a column of a db table

Tags: c#

someone plz give me the query to select the last value entered to a column of a table of a sql database....

Comment: What Database are u using? Whats your table structure like?

Comment: For a vague answer, do an `ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1`. You specify what column you want to order by.

Answer (score 1):

In general after inserting a row into a table, you want to immediately retrieve and store the *last insert id*.

Then simply do a `select * where id=<the last insert id>`.

[MySQL documentation on last insert id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/getting-unique-id.html)

However in the case where you need to retrieve the last insert'ed row for a row that was inserted at a previous point in time (and the *last_insert_id* is not available) you have two main options:

- If there is a unique auto-incrementing ID field, select the row with the highest ID
- Have a `date/time` or `timestamp` field in the table that records exactly when a row is inserted. Then simply select the row with the latest date/time value.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a mechanism first of all to identify which row was inserted when, or at least which row was inserted after a certain row. Your best choice is to have a auto incrementing field or a timestamp.

Once that is figured out, it is actually a simple process

You have not specified the database, so assuming it is SQL Server,

For auto incrementing id

```
SELECT TOP 1 *ColumnYouWant* FROM *TableYouWant* [Where Clauses If You Want] ORDER BY *AutoIncrementingField* DESC
```

For Time Stamps

```
SELECT TOP 1 *ColumnYouWant* FROM *TableYouWant* [Where Clauses If You Want] ORDER BY *TimeStampField* DESC
```

---

For MySQL

```
SELECT *ColumnYouWant* FROM *TableYouWant* [Where Clauses If You Want] ORDER BY *AutoIncrementingField* DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: It will be greatly appreciated if whoever down voted the answer, to explain the reason why :)